# CSS resize image smaller than container when changing window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add some small .pngs on my page and have them resize with the rest of the components when changing the window size.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and apply img-fluid for the larger items, which works great.

Is there a way to apply the exact same behaviour for the small images which don't resize at all when shrinking the window?

edit: Also if it makes any difference, I am using Angular 2's framework.
In the code below, the first image shrinks with the window, while the second one doesn't. I am trying to achieve the same behaviour for both.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://grisha.org/images/sasha_five.png" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/the-middle-ages/500/Knight_Military-128.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: define this code for css: img {width: 100% }

Comment: share some code or a snippet

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using small .pngs, you can use img-thumbnail class and you need to remove img-responsive class